# find the mean for every 12 rows and write the output to a new csv file with year and mean value

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset with Month and year in one column and closing rate of "AXA" in another column in a csv file[snippet of csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vBcp.png). For example, I  need to find the  average closing rate for year 2017 and write the average closing rate into new csv file with company name("AXA") and year. Like above example, i need to do for years available it fom 2009 to 2017

Comment: Can you share sample data with `dput(head(df))`? PS: The image is not visible

Answer (score 0):

From what I understood of the question, I created a reproducible example with only 2 years, I'm using the `lubridate` package to deal with date formats

```
dates <- c('1-1-2009', '1-2-2009', '1-3-2009', '1-4-2009', '1-5-2009', '1-6-2009',
 '1-7-2009', '1-8-2009', '1-9-2009', '1-10-2009', '1-11-2009', '1-12-2009', 
 '1-1-2010', '1-2-2010', '1-3-2010', '1-4-2010', '1-5-2010', '1-6-2010', '1-7-2010',
 '1-8-2010', '1-9-2010', '1-10-2010', '1-11-2010', '1-12-2010')
set.seed(42)
prices <- rnorm(24, mean = 300, sd = 15)

library(lubridate)
Axa <- data.frame(dates = dmy(dates), prices = prices)
Axa <- Axa %>% mutate(obs_year = year(dates)) %>% group_by(obs_year) %>%  
 summarise(prices = mean(prices))
```

Wich gives the following result

```
# A tibble: 2 x 2
   obs_year prices
     <dbl>  <dbl>
1     2009   311.
2     2010   292.
```

This should work for all the different years you have on your file

For reading and writing the files I assume you know how to use `read.csv` and `write.csv`